# Stored procedure using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I want to use stored procedure to add and delete hierarchical data using hibernate. For doing that I want to first check if that procedure exist in database and if not create it. I looked for the standard way of doing this in hibernate but found nothing. I am just curious to know that is it good to create a procedure using hibernate or is there a better way of doing operation on hierarchical data in hibernate.

I am calling webservice from my app that is using the stored procedure to return data in a hierarchical format. If the procedure is deleted at runtime unknowingly, my app will never be able to retrieve data. So what I want if procedure does not exist create it. I am not sure is it the right way or not?
I need guidance...

Comment: [how to create and call stored procedures in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977390/how-to-create-and-call-stored-procedures-in-hibernate)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda The linked question does not have an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call stored function or procedure in Hibernate as follow,

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?,?) }");
    call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER ); // or whatever it is
    call.setLong(2, id);
    call.setLong(3, transId);
    call.execute();
    int result = call.getInt(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
  }
});
```

Similarly

```
int result = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Integer>() {
  @Override
   public Integer  execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?,?) }");
    call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER ); // or whatever it is
    call.setLong(2, id);
    call.setLong(3, transId);
    call.execute();
    return call.getInt(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
  }
});
```